# importing empty setting from .ini file

Tags: regex, powershell

it's quite simple but i can't get my head around it,
i'm trying to import a .ini file into powershell

i got this list

> `[IT]
>   \\foo\bar1=123.123.123.123
>   \\foo\bar2
>   [Marketing]
>   \\foo\bar3=123.123.123.123
>   \\foo\bar4=123.123.123.123`

and this code

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
 $ini = @{}
 switch -regex -file $FilePath
 {
    "^\[(.+)\]" # Section
    {
        $section = $matches[1]
        $ini[$section] = @{}
        $CommentCount = 0
    }
    "^(;.*)$" # Comment
    {
        $value = $matches[1]
        $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
        $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
    } 
    "(.+?)\s*=(.*)" # Key
    {
        $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
    }
 }
 return $ini
}
```

i just can't find the right regex to only get "\foo\bar2"

Comment: So of those three cases, what is `\\foo\bar2` supposed to match against? A section is wrapped in square brackets, a comment is starts with a semicolon, and a key contains an equals sign in it...

Comment: it should be a key whiteout a value.. so i can see if the key is set or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would think that you could just make the `=` optional and all would be dandy.

"(.+?)\s*=**?**(.*)"

However when you try and make the `=` optional the regex "(.+?)" you have will gobble up the whole string making it harder to split the contents using the `$matches` logic you had. You should change the switch so that it will only match each line once. Then you can assume the default action will be performed on a "key" as all other lines would be matched already. Note the `continue`s below

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
 $ini = @{}
 switch -regex -file $FilePath
 {
    "^\[(.+)\]" # Section
    {
        $section = $matches[1]
        $ini[$section] = @{}
        $CommentCount = 0
        continue
    }
    "^(;.*)$" # Comment
    {
        $value = $matches[1]
        $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
        $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        continue
    } 
    default # Key
    {
        $name,$value = $_.split("=")
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value
    }
 }
 return $ini
}
```

## Sample output

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                         
IT                             {\\foo\bar1, \\foo\bar2}                                                                                                      
Marketing                      {\\foo\bar3, \\foo\bar4}  


(Get-IniContent c:\temp\file.ini).IT

Name                           Value                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                         
\\foo\bar1                     123.123.123.123                                                                                                               
\\foo\bar2
```

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of this... Thanks for that quick reply

Answer (score 0):

This will match all `\\foo\bar`

```
\\\\foo\\bar\d?
```

**[demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hX7zQ6/1)**

if you want to match `\\foo\bar2`, use

```
\\\\foo\\bar2
```